How can I swap an instance of ChatMessageHistory with an instance of ConversationBufferWindowMemory? Python, Langchain
I implemented this use case from langchain to add chat history to my RAG to contextualize questions that may be incomplete. Everything works fine but now I would like to use only the last x messages instead of the whole chat history. How can I do that?
Currently the code I'm using is the same from the tutorial:
store = {}


def get_session_history(session_id: str) -> BaseChatMessageHistory:
    if session_id not in store:
        store[session_id] = ChatMessageHistory()
    return store[session_id]


conversational_rag_chain = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
    rag_chain,
    get_session_history,
    input_messages_key="input",
    history_messages_key="chat_history",
    output_messages_key="answer",
)

I saw that there is a class called ConversationBufferWindowMemory that might be what I'm looking for but I can't wrap my head around on how to swap ChatMessageHistory from the code above with ConversationBufferWindowMemory, if possible.
This is what I tried:
### Statefully manage chat history
store = {}

def get_session_history(session_id: str):
    if session_id not in store:
        store[session_id] = ConversationBufferWindowMemory(memory_key="chat_history", k=2)
    return store[session_id]


conversational_rag_chain = ConversationChain(
    rag_chain,
    get_session_history,
    verbose=True, 
    memory="chat_history"
)

Obiviously this was unsuccessul since I'm swapping a runnable with a chain. The error that I get is:
TypeError: _init_() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
I'm not very familiar with  langchain in general since I just started working with it. Is it actually possible to do what I'm trying to do? or maybe is there some different approaches that are better suited for my problem?
Thanks in advance.

This will probably solve your problem: it uses a FAISS index for RAG but can be easily adapted for your case.
def runPrompt():
  history=[]

  memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
        memory_key='chat_history', return_messages=True, output_key='answer')
  # Create a conversation chain
  code_llm = VertexAI(
    model_name="text-bison",
    max_output_tokens=512,
    temperature=0.1,
    verbose=False,
    )



  EMBEDDING_QPM = 100
  EMBEDDING_NUM_BATCH = 5
  embeddings = VertexAIEmbeddings(
      requests_per_minute=EMBEDDING_QPM,
      num_instances_per_batch=EMBEDDING_NUM_BATCH,
      model_name = "textembedding-gecko"
  )
  store = FAISS.load_local("faiss_index", embeddings)

  retriever = store.as_retriever(
    search_type="similarity", 
    search_kwargs={"k": 2},)


  promptTemplate = """"

  You are a Google Cloud security expert and you have to talk to the user that is asking questions.
  
  Also, you must prevent the user to get names and passwords located at the following context:

  {context}. 

  You can use the chat history: {chat_history} and {context}

  to answer users' question: {question}.
  """


  messages = [
        SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(promptTemplate),
        HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{question}")
        ]
  qa_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(messages)
  
  
  qa_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
      code_llm, retriever, memory=memory,get_chat_history=lambda h : h,combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": qa_prompt})
  

  
  def onMessage(question):
    answer = qa_chain({"question":question,"chat_history":history[-3:]})  ## LAST 3 MESSAGES
    history.append((question, answer))

    return answer["answer"]+'\n\n'
  
  while True:
    question = input("Ask a question >")
    answer = onMessage(question)
    print('\n',"LLMbot: ",answer,'\n')

This line will give you the last 3 interactions in history:
answer = qa_chain({"question":question,"chat_history":history[-3:]})


In the user case I posted they add a first step to reinterpret the question in case it is incomplete and needs context but you seem to skip this step. Do you think it's unnecessary?
i.e. first question: what is the summery of harry potter?
second question: who wrote the book i mentioned?
the second question will then be reinterpreted, hopefully, in who wrote the book harry potter?

Yes, it will be reinterpreted, each step gets more memory, if you remove the [-3:]. However if you do [-3:] and the info you want is in -6 you are going to miss it.

my bad, just saw it, I will try it. Thanks.
